# JavaScript: Get element in multidimensional array given list of indices

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
const bannerColletion = [
        ["masaje", "https://hottstuff.com/en/other-services-massages"],
        ["scorts", "https://hottstuff.com/en/other-services-agencies"],
        ["dinero", "https://hottstuff.com/en/make-money"]
];    
bannerToShow = [0,0]
console.log[bannerColletion[bannerToShow]
```

I've tried to convert bannerToShow to string and some other tricks. It didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `reduce` to iterate over the indicies to access, returning the nested value inside the callback:

```js
const bannerColletion = [
        ["masaje", "https://hottdates.com/es/other-services-massages"],
        ["scorts", "https://hottdates.com/es/other-services-agencies"],
        ["dinero", "https://hottdates.com/es/make-money"]
];    
const bannerToShow = [0,0];

console.log(
  bannerToShow.reduce((obj, prop) => obj[prop], bannerColletion)
);
```

Comment: Great. It worked, now I have to understand this sorcery. Thanks, dude.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep recurring on the array of indices, and each time, remove the first index and update the array to the sub list:

```js
const bannerColletion = [
  ["masaje", "https://hottdates.com/es/other-services-massages"],
  ["scorts", "https://hottdates.com/es/other-services-agencies"],
  ["dinero", "https://hottdates.com/es/make-money"]
];

const getElementInMultiDimentionalArray = (arr = [], indices = [])  => {
  // return element at final index if reached
  if(indices.length===1) return arr[indices[0]];
  // recur on element at first index
  const currentIndex = indices.shift();
  if(currentIndex >= arr.length) return;
  return getElementInMultiDimentionalArray(arr[currentIndex], indices);
}

console.log(getElementInMultiDimentionalArray(bannerColletion,[0,0]))
console.log(getElementInMultiDimentionalArray(bannerColletion,[0,1]))
console.log(getElementInMultiDimentionalArray(bannerColletion,[2,1]))
console.log(getElementInMultiDimentionalArray(bannerColletion,[3,3]))
```

Comment: This approach is not generic.

Comment: @iota OP specified that he has a 2d array, why complicate it?

Comment: The question asks about a multidimensional array.

Comment: @iota I didn't notice the title well, I updated the answer to use recursion as the first one already uses a loop

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see an example of an array destruction to achive that

```js
const bannerColletion = [
        ["masaje", "https://hottdates.com/es/other-services-massages"],
        ["scorts", "https://hottdates.com/es/other-services-agencies"],
        ["dinero", "https://hottdates.com/es/make-money"]
];    


var arr = [[0,1],[1,0]]


arr.map(i => {
  
  let [first, second] = i;
  
 
  console.log(bannerColletion[first][second])
              
              
              })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` and keep updating the value (result)

```js
const getValue = (arr, keys) => 
  (value = arr, keys.forEach(key => value = value[key]), value)

const bannerColletion = [
        ["masaje", "https://hottstuff.com/en/other-services-massages"],
        ["scorts", "https://hottstuff.com/en/other-services-agencies"],
        ["dinero", "https://hottstuff.com/en/make-money"]
];    
bannerToShow = [0,0]

console.log(getValue(bannerColletion, bannerToShow))
```

Recursive approach

```js
const getValueRec = (arr, [first, ...keys]) =>
  keys.length ? getValueRec(arr[first], keys) : arr[first];

const bannerColletion = [
  ["masaje", "https://hottstuff.com/en/other-services-massages"],
  ["scorts", "https://hottstuff.com/en/other-services-agencies"],
  ["dinero", "https://hottstuff.com/en/make-money"],
];
bannerToShow = [0, 0];

console.log(getValueRec(bannerColletion, bannerToShow))
```